# Need for new String[0] in the Set toArray() method

Tags: java, set

I am trying to convert a Set to an Array.

```
Set<String> s = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("mango","guava","apple"));
String[] a = s.toArray(new String[0]);
for(String x:a)
      System.out.println(x);
```

And it works fine. But I don't understand the significance of `new String[0]` in `String[] a = s.toArray(new String[0]);`.

I mean initially I was trying `String[] a = c.toArray();`, but it wan't working. Why is the need for `new String[0]`.

Comment: A bit unrelated to the problem but I would use `String[] a = s.toArray(new String[s.size()]);`, so under the hood there's no need to reallocate the array size.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is the array into which the elements of the Set are to be stored, if it is big enough; otherwise, a new array of the same runtime type is allocated for this purpose.

[Object[] toArray()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#toArray%28%29), returns an `Object[]` which cannot be cast to `String[]` or any other type array.

[T[] toArray(T[] a)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#toArray%28T%5b%5d%29) , *returns an array containing all of the elements in this set; the runtime type of the returned array is that of the specified array. If the set fits in the specified array, it is returned therein. Otherwise, a new array is allocated with the runtime type of the specified array and the size of this set.*

If you go through the implementing code (I'm posting the code from [OpenJDK](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.toArray%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29)) , it will be clear for you :

```
 public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a) {
     if (a.length < size)
     // Make a new array of a's runtime type, but my contents:
     return (T[]) Arrays.copyOf(elementData, size, a.getClass());
     System.arraycopy(elementData, 0, a, 0, size);
     if (a.length > size)
         a[size] = null;
    return a;
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

The parameter is a result of one of the many well-known limitations in the Java generics system. Basically, the parameter is needed in order to be able to return an array of the correct type.