# Dumping a collection to array using toArray

Tags: java, arrays, collections

I was reading about java collections from [The Collection Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/collection.html) which reads:

> Suppose that `c` is a known to contain only strings (perhaps because `c` is of type `Collection<String>`). The following snippet dumps the contents of `c` into a newly allocated array of `String` whose length is identical to the number of elements in `c`.

```
String[] a = c.toArray(new String[0]);
```

ps. `c` is a collection

My question is, why do we needed to pass `new String[0]` to `c.toArray`? What does passing `new String[0]` do and what's the difference if we remove it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need for new String\[0\] in the Set toArray() method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16459590/need-for-new-string0-in-the-set-toarray-method). See also: [make arrayList.toArray() return more specific types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061640/make-arraylist-toarray-return-more-specific-types)

Comment: You could just pass in c.size() which is what it is checking anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a)` is preferable because you will obtain a `T[]` type instead that a raw Object type. This because Java is unable to create an array of a specific type at runtime without passing the type directly to the method, indeed `a.getClass()` is used to obtain a `Class<T[]>` reference (because of type erasure).

In addition passing a `new T[0]` will cause a double allocation of the array. You can directly pass a correctly sized array to avoid any overhead:

```
String[] a = c.toArray(new String[c.size()]);
```

Comment: A [link](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.toArray%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) to the source code referred to in the answer.