# How to separate String

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist

How can i separate a string of **(?abcd.efgdf)?**

What i want to get is the **"?abcd"** and the **"efgdf"** being separate and transferred to another string container.

I know the use of split(".") , but what if there are two string like this. 
ex. **(?abcd.efgdf) (?xcv.qwer)** splitting the second string contains the end of 1st string which is **"efgdf"**. so using split(".") is not an option.

Is there any kind of implementation of separating this string?

Comment: What should happen in the second case?. Do you want 4 different values?. Please show us the output explicitly

Comment: sorry, my bad. the output should be of the example **(?abcd.efgdf) (?xcv.qwer)** is      **"?abcd" , "?xcv"** transferred to a arraylist1 , and **"efgdf", "qwer"** transferred to a arraylist2 @TheLostMind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Regex `\(|\.|\)\s*\(|\)\??`.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/Pe5aCT/1)

It includes all of these delimiters:

1. `(` first opening bracket
2. `.` a period
3. `)\s*(` optional whitespace**s** between brackets.
4. `)` closing bracket
5. `?` optional question mark following point #4
   .

But it may create some empty strings so using java 8 streams, you can remove them. Here's the code

**Test case 1**

```
String s = "(?abcd.efgdf)?";
String[] arr = Arrays.asList(s.split("\\(|\\.|\\)\\s*\\(|\\)\\??")).stream().filter(str -> !str.isEmpty()).collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray(new String[0]);
for (String a: arr) System.out.println(a);
```

**Output**

```
?abcd
efgdf
```

**Test case 2**

```
String s = "(?abcd.efgdf) (?xcv.qwer)";
String[] arr = Arrays.asList(s.split("\\(|\\.|\\)\\s*\\(|\\)\\??")).stream().filter(str -> !str.isEmpty()).collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray(new String[0]);
for (String a: arr) System.out.println(a);
```

**Ouput**

```
?abcd
efgdf
?xcv
qwer
```

Comment: can you explain how does **.stream().filter(str -> !str.isEmpty()).collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray(new String[0]);** works? @RamanSahasi

Comment: @johnedgarotom **stream** -> convert list to stream; **filter(str -> !str.isEmpty())** -> filters out empty strings, **collect** -> collect the output and convert streams to a List; **toArray()** -> converts list to array

Comment: @johnedgarotom see this question [Need for new `String[0]` in the Set toArray() method](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16459590/2815219)

Answer (score 0):

You can split your `String` with **two delimiters** with `point` and with `space` like this :

```
String [] spl = "(?abcd.efgdf) (?xcv.qwer)".split("\\.| ");
//---------------------------------------------------^-^--
```

So you will get :

```
(?abcd
efgdf)
(?xcv
qwer)
```

If your `str = "(?abcd.efgdf)"` you will get :

```
(?abcd
efgdf)
```

Comment: i'll try sir @YCF_L

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [java.util.Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)
which will help you parse the whole string for those patterns you are looking for.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\((\?\w*)\.(\w*)\)");
Matcher m = p.matcher("(?abcd.efgdf) (?xcv.qwer)");
while (m.find()) {
    list1.add(m.group(1));
    list2.add(m.group(2));
}
```

Regular expressions might seem intimidating at first, but are well worth it for more complex cases. Read through the JavaDoc of Pattern to understand the possiblities. They will help in your example as they will get rid of all the spaces and brackets for you, so you only eal with what you are looking for, not what is in between. Furthermore, this works for strings containing any number of those `(?abcd.abcd)` groups.